# Reading nested JSON containing Arrays with Timeseries in pandas dateframe

Tags: arrays, json, pandas, nested, time-series

I know there are most likely many questions like this, but i could not find an answer.
I have a json object that contains time Series data and i have trouble loading it into a Dataframe.

The data contains timesieres data like this:

```
    {


    "categories": [
            "02.01.2007",
            "03.01.2007",
            "04.01.2007",
        ...
        ],
    unixtime": [
            "1167696000",
            "1167782400",
            "1167868800",
        ... 
        ],
    "series": [
            {
                "au": [
                    {
                        "name": "Gold",
                        "data": [
                            15.51,
                            15.48,
                        ...
                        ],
                        "color": "#FFD200"
                    }
                ],
                  "ag": [
                    {
                        "name": "Silber",
                        "data": [
                            315.21,
                            313.97,
                             ...
                        ],
                        "color": "#FFD200"
                    }
                ],
               ...
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

All in all there is price data from 7 metals (au,ag,pt,pd,rh,ir,ru). categories contians a list of time stamps, unixtime as well in a different format, Than comes the series object itself, which is nested and contains Objects which each have a field data that contains the prices i want to convert into pandas Time series data.

My code is however not working

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
r = # http request
j = r.json()
data = pd.json_normalize(data=j)
```

is not working. i gues i have to use the record_path keyword but i do not understand it. I wand a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
 | Categories |  unixtime  |  au   |  ag    | ... |
1| 02.01.2007 | 1167696000 | 15.51 | 315.21 | ... |
2| 03.01.2007 | 1167782400 | 15.48 | 313.97 | ... |
3| ...
```

thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you show us expected sample output

Comment: @NorrinRadd Assuming the JSON file name is `data.json`, have you tried `df = pd.read_json('data.json')`?